# How do I show the GRUB menu in GRUB 2

Tags: grub2, menu

How do I show the GRUB menu in GRUB 2 during boot up?

Answer (score 0):

You can get to the Grub 2 menu by holding the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key down on startup and not letting it go until the menu appears.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to enable the menu by default, check the line `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT` in the file `/etc/default/grub`. This option does the following:

```
Wait this many seconds for a key to be pressed before displaying
the menu.  If no key is pressed during that time, display the menu
for the number of seconds specified in GRUB_TIMEOUT before booting
the default entry. We expect that most people who use
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT will want to have GRUB_TIMEOUT set to `0' so
that the menu is not displayed at all unless a key is pressed.
Unset by default.
```

As you see it is unset by default, so check whether it has been set or not in your case.